# Uncaught object that's exist - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm facing a comportment on jquery witch i'm not understanding, neither fixing.

I got this structure in a php

```
<div class="tutProgress">
    <div class="progressStep ball"></div>
    <div class="progressStep ball"></div>
    <div class="progressStep ball"></div>
    <div class="progressStep ball"></div>
    <div class="progressStep ball"></div>
</div>
```

and i'm trying to access using jquery.

```
var $text = [..., ".tutProgress," ...]
let $filled = $text.find(".progressStep");
for(var i = 0; i < progress; i++){
    $filled[i].css("background-color", "#3498DB");
}
```

I keep getting uncaught object `$filled[i].css` is not a function. Why this happening and how to fix?

Thanks forwards!

EDIT NOTE: the $text array content is not important. It's filled with a bunch of classes names

Comment: `$text` is not a jQuery object in this snippet, so you cannot perform `find()` off it.

Comment: @Taplar No, you can't call jQuery methods on the results of a plain JS Array `.find`.

Comment: A simple css rule would do this

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid jQuery selector as well. `:(` You have got any more code to share?

Comment: @DaveNewton That's what he meant.

Comment: What's wrong with just this CSS selector: `.tutProgress {background-color:#3498D;}`?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman ... Then should have said so, because you *can* call `find` on the code as shown. The problem happens earlier than Taplar indicates.

Comment: Ohhh Okay @DaveNewton.

Comment: the strange part is the find method is working and when a console this returns an array of all div's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you access `$filled[i]`, this is an array of html elements, and no jquery elements. The `.css` function is defined in jquery elements, so you must access it like this:

```
$($filled[i]).css(..........)
```

Comment: But it's not array of elements either

Comment: No, it's an array of somethings, and a string.

Comment: that worked! but i still not sure if i can tell the difference between an jquery element and a html element!! :O

Comment: Dave, the array is filled with class names. Sorry about that. I'm gonna edit to avoid misunderstandings!